# Re-use git trees on push

Tags: git

**Preamble:**

I am experimenting with using the deduplication feature of git for binary deployments.

Yes, i know most sources say this is a *bad idea (tm)*, but in my tests so far this actually works great.

I would like to have one branch for each version, with each branch being an orphan, that is, containing a single commit without any parents.

On the client side, with fetch, this works great.

I do a `git init` and `git remote add origin [url]` and then only fetch the specific version with `git fetch origin [version]`.

On the first fetch, it fetches everything, on subsequent updates, it can reuse a large chunk of the objects.

---

**Issue: Observed behavior on push:**

When I do a push, it always pushes everything, ignoring any unchanged files.
Even if I push the exact same tree twice with different commits, it will push everything each time.

As I understand this, it is because the pushed commit doesn't have any parents.

If there is a parent-child relation, it will reuse objects on push instead.

**Question:**

Is there a way to tell git to reuse objects on push, even if the commit that I am pushing is an orphan?

I guess a workaround could be to have a linear history of commits, then do a `git fetch --depth 1` on the client.

Comment: Git uses some shortcuts to avoid doing a full tree walk so that sometimes it does not know that a receiving repository has particular objects. In this case the push code doesn't check the other branch names, even though in theory it *could*. If you experiment further you may find additional corner cases where the object revision list code doesn't explore parts of the DAG that you wish it would. Microsoft have been working on this code a bunch in the last year+ to improve it.

Comment: You could use git tags instead of orphan branches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I create a dummy commit, that *does* have a parent, and shares a tree with the orphan, then push both of them at the same time, git can figure it out:

Let's say I have two orphan branches, v1 and v2. v1 was already pushed to the server, now I want to push v2.

If I do just `git push origin v2:refs/heads/v2`, then it pushes everything.

But this works:

Create a new dummy commit from the same tree
`v2-dummy` = `git commit-tree v2^{tree} -p v1 -m "v2"`

Push both of them with the same command (this is the important part)
`git push origin v2-dummy:refs/heads/v22-dummy v2:refs/heads/v2`

delete the dummy
`git push -d origin v2-dummy`

Comment: ...I'm confused. Is this supposed to be a self-answer (fine, but it doesn't read like one) or an update to your question (in which case it should be _edited into_ the question)? This section is only for answers.

Comment: yeah, it's an answer, I found a solution (dummy commit with parent, push both of them at the same time)

Answer (score 1):

When you push with Git, the two sides negotiate which objects they each have, and then the client pushes any missing data to the server.  The way they do this depends on the protocol, but essentially they negotiate based on the refs in use plus additional items that both sides can reach from them.

If you have a large number of orphan branches, Git is unlikely to try to walk other refs, since it assumes that they probably don't share many objects in common.  The exact details are not documented, but this is usually a safe assumption.  The revision walking algorithm used during fetches and pushes is not customizable, because (a) usually it works well and (b) usually sending a small number of duplicate objects is not harmful.

In general, though, as most sources have told you, this is a bad idea.  Git is not a good deployment tool for many reasons.  There are tools which are better suited to this and more flexible, like Capistrano.